# Finding Distinct Terminal and Nonterminals Symbols

Tags: haskell, context-free-grammar

I am currently working on writing two functions that will be used to return lists of all distinct terminals that appear in a given grammar.

Here is the type for Grammar :

```
data Grammar = Grammar [Prod]
               deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Here is what I have so far :

```
terminals :: Grammar -> [String]                                          
terminals ts = nub [ x | x <-ts]

nonterms  :: Grammar -> [String]
nonterms nt = nub [ x | x <- nt]
```

Where the grammar that is being placed into the function would be something like this (3 Examples) :

```
g4 = "P -> true ; P -> false; P -> not P ; P -> P and P"
g5 = "P -> P & N; P -> N; N -> ~ N; N -> t"                                   
g6 = "P -> N & P; P -> N; N -> ~ N; N -> t"
```

However though, the functions that I am using do not work because GHCI could not match expected type ‘[String]’ with actual type ‘Grammar’.

I am going off of the basic principles of Context-free grammars (CFGs), that a context-free grammar is

```
 G = (T,N,P,S)
```

Where T is a set T of terminal symbols ("tokens"), a set N of nonterminal symbols, a set P of productions, and a start symbol S.

How could I use / write two functions that could return lists of all the distinct terminals (respectively nonterminals) that appear in a given grammar. Three examples of grammars above. Thank you.

Comment: `Grammar` isn't a type that's built in to Haskell. Please post its definition.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
terminals :: Grammar -> [String]                                          
terminals ts = nub [ x | x <-ts]
```

Your function `terminals` is typed as returning a `[String]`. Its implementation returns the result of `nub`. `nub` has type `Eq a => [a] -> [a]`, so for it to return a `[String]`, its input must be a `[String]` as well. This implies that `[ x | x <-ts]` must be of type `[String]`, and then that `x` must be of type `String`. Doing `x <- ts` in a list comprehension means that `ts` must be a list of whatever type `x` is, so in this case, `ts` must be `[String]`.

Now the problem becomes apparent. Given the type of the output of your function and its implementation, `ts` must be of type `[String]`, but given the type of the input of your function, `ts` must be of type `Grammar`. Since `[String]` and `Grammar` are different types, this causes the type error that you're seeing.

Side note: `[ x | x <-ts]` is exactly equivalent to just `ts`, and `[ x | x <- nt]` is exactly equivalent to just `nt`.